# Total LI width calculate and set the parent UL or DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to calculated Total LI width and set the width for parent div.

My example code:

```
<ul>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
<li>dsfdsfdsfds</li>
</ul>
```

Css Style :

```
ul li{width:400px;float:left;}
```

Comment: Why do we need to calculate it? Just make the parent `inline-block` or float it...won't that do the same thing?

Comment: I need to calculate width and set the parent div, incase that outer width is only 1024px. so other li come down.

Comment: You can simply use `ul li{display:block}`. For code efficiency and fast rendering, assign a class to ul and style `li` who falls under that class. eg.
`.classname li{display:block}`. `.classname li{display:block}` will style to `li` only who falls under `.classname` class and it ignores other `ULs` which might have been used in the page and loads the page a bit faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){      
$('.nested_li ul').each(function(){  
        var liItems = $(this);
        var Sum = 0;
        if(liItems.children('li').length >= 1){
         $(this).children('li').each(function(i, e){
                Sum += $(e).outerWidth(true);
         });
        $(this).width(Sum+1);
        } 
});

    });
</script>
```